# Javascript - Need Simple Code That Does The Very Basic Thing Of WYSWYIG Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor

I need a javascript codes that I can use to get started in making my own wysywig editor, since I could not find any editor that matches my requirements.

What I need is only a piece of codes that does **only** the following thing to contenteditable element:

- wrap/ toggle wrap selected texts with defined tags containing attribute, such as: `<span class="someclass"></span>`
- preserve the text highlighting/ selection while wrapping and unwrapping.

I found out rangy and SimpleMDE, but it has gone too advanced for me to understand. So, I am looking for an alternative with the most basic and simplest codes.

Comment: There are several on world wide web. Find one check the source files. Wouldn't that help you instead asking here which won't get any answer but losing reps only.

Comment: Also these editors are js based so better start learning basics of it to get started.

Comment: I did, but I am just desperate, because it has around 3 days and still get only a little progress.

Comment: Then I am afraid it's quite tricky to develop.